# C# Open generic type comparison. Generic<> is "parent" of Generic<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, comparison, open-generics

I have a class MyGeneric<T>, and some cached data created from type MyGeneric<string>, MyGeneric<int>, MyGeneric<double>... etc.

Somewhere I have to check certain data to see if it is MyGeneric, I code like this:

```
if (data is MyGeneric<>) { // can't compile
    // ... do something
}
```

or

```
if (data.GetType() == typeof(MyGeneric<>)
    || typeof(MyGeneric<>).isAssginableFrom(data.GetType())) { 
    // no exception but none of these comparison works
}
```

or this kind of stupid implemention works but i'd like to throw it away:

```
if (data.GetType().Name.StartsWith(typeof(MyGeneric<>).Name) { ... }
```

Is there a way to check relations between actual data type and open generic type (MyGeneric<>) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call *open generic type* is known as *generic type definition*:

```
if(data.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyGeneric<>))
{

}
```